# setPreferredSize alernative calling for TextBox widths and heights not working

Tags: codenameone

TextFields grow automatically after move to next filed,if we consider more text on that only. To fix this we used setPrefferredSize(Dimension d) code, but in latest code this method is deprecated. So we apply setSameHeight/Width methods to TextFields.

```
TextField loginId= new TextField("", "", 10, TextArea.ANY);
loginId.setHeight(60);
loginId.setWidth(320);
TextField password= new TextField("", "", 10, TextArea.ANY);
password.setHeight(60);
password.setWidth(320); 
Component.setSameWidth(loginId,password);
Component.setSameHeight(loginId,password);
```

The above code is not working for dynamic grow of textFields when it has more data in that.

What is wrong in my code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`setPreferredSize` would be problematic here as this should change e.g. based on device orientation, font size etc.

Both components will have the same width/height and both will grow in sync based on that code so this isn't an effective way to limit the growth.

The perspective of looking at the components for this is wrong, you should look at the layout. E.g. if you want text fields to take up a smaller portion of the screen you can use table layout which is very suitable for such cases and use the width constraint. See the developer guide [section on layouts](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/basics.html).

Comment: On table layout also code not working the text sizes grows when it has more data. please find this code -> Form hi = new Form("Hi World", new TableLayout(3, 1));
        TextField t1 = new TextField();
        t1.setWidth(200);
        TextField t2 = new TextField();
        TextField t3 = new TextField();
        t2.setWidth(200);
        t3.setWidth(200);
        hi.addComponent(t1);
        hi.addComponent(t2);
        hi.addComponent(t3);
        Component.setSameWidth(t1,t2,t3);
        //hi.addComponent(new Label("Hi World"));
        hi.show();

Comment: FYI, setSize(Dimension d) method on TextField also not working for this dynamic growing the textfileds sizes with text.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the setWidth/Height (and obviously setSize etc.) would be totally redundant as those only make sense if you are writing your own layout manager. I was talking about the width constraint for the layout see the widthPercentage in the sample here: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/table/TableLayout.html